# Best way of making a static nested class constructor parameters immediately available?

Tags: java, oop

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
class Foo 
{
    Object testObj1;
    Object testObj2;

    Foo.Bar BarObj = new Foo.Bar(testObj1, testObj2);
    Object BarObj1 = BarObj.obj1;

    static class Bar
    {
        public Object obj1;
        public Object obj2;

        public Bar(Object obj1, Object obj2)
        {
            this.obj1 = obj1;
            this.obj2 = obj2;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to create a static nested class that makes its constructor parameters immediatly available to any class that instantiates it, is this the best way to do it?

**EDIT:** Okay, It's kind of hard to structure a question when you're not that good at Java. I'm an intermediate android developer, basically, BarObj should contain objects pertaining to a certain functionality in android, for example a 3-button menu. Each button contains some object resources, the Image object containing the button image, the Text object containing the button text etc. etc.

So I want to encapsulate each button with it's own resources into just one object, so that I can just parse that button object to a function that fx. manipulates the button image when the button is clicked. Does that make sense? Here is some updated code:

```
class Foo 
{
    Object Button1Image;
    Object Button1Text;

    Object Button2Image;
    Object Button2Text;

    Foo.Button Button1Obj = new Foo.Button(Button1Image, Button1Text);
    Object Button1ObjImage = Button1Obj.obj1;

    static class Button
    {
        public Object obj1;
        public Object obj2;

        public Button(Object obj1, Object obj2)
        {
            this.obj1 = obj1;
            this.obj2 = obj2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I would rather provide a `getBarObj1()` method that has a `return this.barObj1.obj1;` line.

Comment: It is, but the question is why you want to do that?

Comment: No!!! This is not threadsafe!

Make your class a singleton or something. What is your use case?? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is for android development, basically I need an object that just holds other objects. Or perhaps this is unecessary? It is strictly for encapsulating certain objects to a particular functionality.

Comment: Then create it outside of `Foo` unless it has to be hermetic. Then, obey the standard JavaBean conventions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've confused you guys, I'm on an intermediate level in Java, take a look at my edit for some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with an approach similar to this ?

```
class Foo 
{
    ButtonInformation[] buttons = new ButtonInformation[]{
      new ButtonInformation(image1, "Button 1"),
      new ButtonInformation(image2, "Button 2"),
      new ButtonInformation(image3, "Button 3")
    };

    class ButtonInformation
    {
        public Image buttonImage;
        public String buttonText;

        public ButtonInformation(Image buttonImage, String buttonText)
        {
            this.buttonImage = buttonImage;
            this.buttonText = buttonText;
        }
    }
}
```

to access the information for a button you would do it like this (inside the Foo class):

```
function doSomething(int button) {
   // make sure button is less than the buttons.length.
   Image buttonImage = buttons[button].buttonImage
   String buttonText = buttons[button].buttonText;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong! I hadn't thought about doing it like this. I'm assuming that the method Button inside ButtonInformation should be called ButtonInformation as well, to make it the constructor of the class? And would you say that the way you make the button parameters available to Foo is the best way (declaring them public and then assigning them in the constructor)?

Comment: Ah .. you are right that should be the constructor. The fields of the inner class are already declared public so you can use them from the enclosing class. If you only need the ButtonInformation class from inside the Foo class then this is the way to do it. If you need to create ButtonInformation from outside Foo you need to do it a little different. Based on your code i assumed you only need it inside the Foo class :). Just tell me if this isn't the case.

Comment: I would normally make the ButtonInformation an interface and access the members via get/set methods, but your use case seems better suited to this solution.

Comment: Yes I only need this inside Foo. Which actually brings up another question, what is the intention behind declaring a class static? In this case the ButtonInformation class could be static or non-static, it wouldn't matter right? In this case I might as well declare it static since it just holds some objects, or would that just unecessarily limit my class?

Comment: An inner class (nested class that isn't static) contains an reference to the enclosing class. Implicitly this means you can't instantiate without an instance of the enclosing class. A static nested class doesn't have this so it's just a simple nested class. See here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Using get/setter methods would be the correct way if the objects inside ButtonInformation were changed along the way inside Foo right?

Comment: It also depends on the caller pattern :). But basically that's the idea.